# Seat rail clamp does not lock in the angle of the saddle

Tags: road-bike, saddle, clamp

Just put together this bike which is a VB-r-068, i've tightened it to the point where I can't tighten it anymore yet I can still tilt it and what not. I've greased the threads since I thought that might be the issue. This is steel rails I believe, it is the EC90 "power saddle".

Seat post showing the hole for the clamp (click for larger):

[image: Seat post showing saddle mounting hole]

Clamp mechanism parts (click for larger):

[image: Seat clamp parts]

View of the clamp holding the seat rail of the mounted saddle (click for larger):

[image: Saddle mounted to the seat post]

View of the mounted saddle from behind, showing the clamp (click for larger):

[image: View of mounted saddle from behind, showing the rail attachment]

Assembled clamp mechanism (click for larger):

[image: Clamp mechanism assembled]

[This imgur gallery contains a few more photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kam3t.jpg).

Comment: That just looks like an extremely bad design. Looks like there is nothing which prevents the bolt from turning? Not even serrations? So the same force/torque you use to tighten the bolt can also be used to tilt the clamp.

Comment: yes that's correct unless i'm missing something, the round plastic bit literally just turns when i put down slight force which causes the tilt

Comment: Are there any torque values listed on the clamp area, or is any info available from the manufacturer. I would suggest figuring out the max torque and ensure you are using enough. Also, maybe try assembly paste to increase the grip.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this clamp, but is it possible you're missing a part?  Did you get it new  or used ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a style of clamp that is not specific to the VB-r-068, or even the company that makes them (VeloBuild?).  [Here is an example sold by Trek](https://www.trekbikes.com/gb/en_GB/equipment/cycling-components/bike-seatposts-accessories/bike-seatpost-parts-and-accessories/bontrager-lightweight-emonda-seatpost-ears/p/14141/?colorCode=red):

[image: Exploded view of the Bontrager saddle rail clamp for an Emonda seat post]

It appears that the most likely sources of trouble for this part are not having it tightened enough (I've found equivalent parts marked 10-12Nm or 10-15Nm, which is quite a lot) or having some contamination inside the clamp, as this person notes in his review of the VB-r-068:

It seems your best course of action would be to take it apart and thoroughly clean/degrease the contact surfaces, then reassemble it and make sure it's tightened to at least 10Nm.  ([Source for 10-12Nm](https://www.shoptokeluv.site/product/Seat-Post-Saddle-Clamp-ti-Bolt-For-Trek-bontrager-hylix-zipp-Sl-Speed-round-Rail_80aigimgkppgngj.html), [Source for 10-15Nm](https://www.ebay.com/itm/303317894217))

I did stumble across (meaning I can't find it again) someone who claimed they'd purchased a clamp that had the circular wedges too deep for his seatpost, so they made contact in the middle before clamping sufficiently, but that shouldn't be a problem for the clamp that comes with the bike.